# fetchall function working in python

Tags: python, tornado, psql

I have been trying to execute a query in python Torando framework below and print the result. But instead of the value I am getting empty list as output.

```
 def post(self):
    self.db.execute("SELECT name FROM doctors WHERE doctors.name = '%s'" %usr, callback = self.add_Id)

def add_Id(self, cursor):
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print results
```

Comment: If you're getting an empty list, make sure your query is correct

Comment: What python library are you using to handle database. What's _db_?